# driver.findElement(By.xpath("[@id="smallWidgetDiv"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div")); - syntax error

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am getting a syntax error for the following code, and I can't see why?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("[@id="smallWidgetDiv"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div"));

Error : syntax error on token  "smallWidgetDiv" , invalid assignment operator
```

Comment: Please put the complete error and explain the question like what you have done in order to solve the problem. A more detailed explanation of the code is needed

Answer (score 0):

You are missing double forward slash at the beginning of your xpath. Then, you should provide a specific tag of an element OR use the asterisk `*`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='smallWidgetDiv']/div[1]/div/div/div/div"));
```